# Stating lie as a part of job

Tags: sin, business

I work a job where I need to prepare the students for visa interviews and write their statement of purposes. I often have to write lies about their future plans. Because the UK doesn't want u to stay once your degree completes. It requires u to return. So if you state in the interview that I will seek job there, your visa will be refused. So I prepare the students in such a way that they have to lie to about not staying in the UK. Is such a lie permissible?